# How to create batch file to take user input and create a text file?

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file `test.txt`

The contents of `test.txt` are:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

I want to create a batch file `"process.bat"` which takes `3 inputs` from user:

```
input 1
input 2
input 3
```

and create a text file `"output.txt"` with below output:

```
input 1 input 2 "input 3" xxx Hello
input 1 input 2 "input 3" yyy Hello
input 1 input 2 "input 3" zzz Hello
```

Comment: So what have you coded so far?

Comment: Post what did you tried so far as code and explain more your aim !

Comment: Consider looking into the `SET` and `ECHO` commands.  Specifically, `SET /P` and `ECHO>>{filename} {text}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are looking for:

```
ECHO off
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion

ECHO Path to test.txt
SET /p filepath=
CD %filepath%

ECHO Input 1
SET /p input1=

ECHO Input 2
SET /p input2=

ECHO Input 3
SET /p input3=

( FOR /f %%i IN (test.txt) DO (
ECHO %input1% %input2% "%input3%" %%i Hello >> output.txt
))

:eof
```

If you wanted to just hard code the file path in it would just be:

```
SET /p filepath=yourfilepathhere
CD %filepath%
```